# Click & Grow Bug Infestation

Tags: pest-control, basil, bugs

Our 4 week old Click & Grow Basil pods are sprouting nicely, and suddenly we have a tiny white bug infestation! How to get rid of them? Don't want to use chemicals as we plan to consume the basil, and cannot rinse under water faucet since the pods are encased in the Click & Grow housing. We live in CT and it's winter (about 12-20 degrees outside, and 67 degrees inside). Where did the bugs come from - non-sterile soil? Helpful tips appreciated!

Comment: Hello Beth.  Sorry to hear about your infestation.  Can you please post pictures of these bugs.   Also a picture of a Click & Grow unit for those unfamiliar with this product.  And possibly a description of what a Click & Grow is?   Anything to help.   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are they [whiteflies?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitefly) These are pretty much always around in small numbers, even in winter. If your plants are stressed then you get infection.

Stresses can include a variety of things. One really common one is being close to forced air heating ducts. Or in the summer being close to the A/C. The dry air flow can stress many types of plant. My hibiscus really stresses near the heat duct and gets whiteflies in the winter.

Some other possible sources of stress are wrong watering schedule, improper fertilizer, wrong light level, and wrong temperature. It may be a chore trying to figure out which and how to fix it.

Depending on the plant, insecticidal soap can help. There are a few brand names. As the name suggests, it is just soap. You spray it right on the affected plants, right on the insects. It coats the eggs and the adults, killing them. And it coats the leaves, giving limited protection. It washes off before you eat the crop. Many plants don't mind the coating of soap, but experiment on a small area first.

However, if the stress is still there they flies will be back. Try to find out what the stress is and remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Given your plants are still seedlings it's best to cut your losses and start again.

The soil may have already been contaminated before you ever brought them home.

There is an organic solution but...
Small seedlings may not be able to handle diluted oil

I know it takes ages to get it started but it sounds like it's time to press the reset button :)